# Nested Interval Theorem: Another part

Tags: real-analysis

Let [a1, b1] ⊇ [a2, b2] ⊇ · · · be a sequence of intervals. If lim(bi − ai) → 0, then ∩[an, bn] is a singleton set.

I have proved the first part which says that the infinite intersection of such subsets is not empty and is a closed interval. But how do I prove this part? I tried solving it by assuming that the intersection contains two unequal numbers x and y. And then by generating real numbers between them I was trying to reach some kind of contradiction but was not able to proceed.
Can someone help me with this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume two different points x and y. Both of them are of the form  $a(n)<X<b(n) , a(n)<y<b(n)$. So $0<|x-y|<|a(n)-b(n)|< €$. Difference of two constant number is less than any positive number €>0. Deduce that $X=y$

Answer (score 0):

If you have proved that the intersection is a closed interval, then if you assume there exist $x$ and $y$ distinct in the intersection you have the whole interval $[x, y] $ in it as well. This is impossible since it has positive measure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Conclude the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are increasing and decreasing, respectively.
2. Since $[a_n, b_n]$ is a closed interval, $a_n \leq b_n$. So conclude that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded above and below, respectively.
3. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, they converge. That is, $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$.
4. Then $\bigcap_n [a_n, b_n]=[a,b]$
5. But since $b_n - a_n \rightarrow 0$, by the algebra of limits, we have that $a=b$.
6. Therefore, $[a,b]=\{ x\}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We can also conclude that $x$ is unique.